# How to install all Ubuntu studio and Edu_ubuntu pakages into BOSS linux by terminal?

Tags: software-installation

I run following command to install Ubuntu Studio packages.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-plugins ubuntustudio-graphics ubuntustudio-video`
but following error occur during installation

**E: Unable to locate package** mailtuils how to resolve that?
And what is appropriate method to install all 
**Edubuntu and ubuntu studio packages** into BOSS Linux.

Comment: Please edit your question to copy and paste the screen output of the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. BOSS is based on Debian and isn't an Ubuntu-derivative so those packages aren't in the BOSS repositories. The packages you mention are all "meta packages": a sort of "fake" package that simply installs other packages. So you will have to go to http://packages.ubuntu.com and get the list of packages described by each meta package.

For example, [`ubuntustudio-video`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/ubuntustudio-video) contains:

```
libavcodec-extra
osspd
audacity
blender
brasero
devede
ffmpeg
ffmpeg2theora
inkscape
kdenlive
khelpcenter
libav-tools
openshot
pitivi
subtitleeditor
synfigstudio
vokoscreen
xjadeo
```

However, [`libavcodec-extra`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libavcodec-extra57) is itself a meta package containing:

```
libavutil55
libc6
libcrystalhd3
libgsm1
liblzma5
libmp3lame0
libopencore-amrnb0
libopencore-amrwb0
libopenjpeg5
libopus0
libschroedinger-1.0-0
libshine3
libsnappy1v5
libspeex1
libswresample2
libtheora0
libtwolame0
libva1
libvo-amrwbenc0
libvorbis0a
libvorbisenc2
libvpx3
libwavpack1
libwebp6
libwebpmux2
libx264-148
libx265-79
libxvidcore4
libzvbi0
zlib1g
```

This means you can install everything installed by `ubuntustudio-video` with:

```
sudo apt-get install osspd audacity blender brasero devede ffmpeg \
ffmpeg2theora inkscape kdenlive khelpcenter libav-tools \
openshot pitivi subtitleeditor synfigstudio vokoscreen xjadeo \
libavutil55 libc6 libcrystalhd3 libgsm1 liblzma5 libmp3lame0 \
libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0 libopenjpeg5 libopus0 \
libschroedinger-1.0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libspeex1 libswresample2 \
libtheora0 libtwolame0 libva1 libvo-amrwbenc0 libvorbis0a \
libvorbisenc2 libvpx3 libwavpack1 libwebp6 libwebpmux2 libx264-148 \
libx265-79 libxvidcore4 libzvbi0 zlib1g
```